# HDF5 in Java: What are the difference between the availabe APIs?

Tags: java, hdf5

I've just discovered the HDF5 format and I'm considering using it to store 3D data spread over a cluster of Java application servers. I have found out that there are several implementations available for Java, and would like to know the differences between them:

- [Java HD5 Interface (JHI5)](http://www.hdfgroup.org/hdf-java-html/JNI/jhi5/index.html) The Java wrapper from the HDF group itself.
- [JHDF5 (HDF5 for Java)](https://wiki-bsse.ethz.ch/display/JHDF5/JHDF5+%28HDF5+for+Java%29)
- [Permafrost](http://code.google.com/p/permafrost/)
- [Nujan: Pure Java NetCDF4 and HDF5 writer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nujan/) (cannot read HDF5)

Most importantly, I would like to know:

- How much of the native API is covered, any limitations that do not
  exist in the native API?
- If there is support for "Parallel HDF5"?
- Once my 3D data is loaded, do I get a "native call overhead"
  each time I access one element in a 3D array? That is, do the data
  actually gets turned into Java objects, or stay in "native/JNI
  memory"?
- Is there any know *stability* problems with a particular
  implementation, since a crash in native code normally takes the whole
  JVM down?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

HDF Java follows a layered approach:

- JHI5 - the low level JNI wrappers: very flexible, but also quite tedious to use.
- Java HDF object package - a high-level interface based on JHI5.
- HDFView - a Java-based viewer application based on the Java HDF object package.

JHDF5 provides a high-level interface building on the JHI5 layer which provides most of the functionality of HDF5 to Java. The API has a shallow learning curve and hides most of the house-keeping work from the developer. You can run the Java HDF object package (and HDFView) on the JHI5 interface that is part of JHDF5, so the two APIs can co-exist within one Java program.

Permafrost and Nujan seem far from being complete at this point and Permafrost hasn't seen a lot of activity recently, so they appear to be not the first choice at this point in time.

I think a good path for you is to have a look at both the Java HDF5 object package and JHDF5, decide which one of the two APIs fit your needs better and go with that one.

Disclaimer: I have worked on the JHDF5 interface, so I may be biased.

Answer (score 8):

Just wanted to point out another option, [jhdf.io](http://jhdf.io) it's a pure Java library for HDF5. Currently it is read only and doesn't cover the full HDF5 specification. However it can open and read lots of HDF5 files, and I hope to improve it over time. Being pure Java it is much easier to integrate into other Java projects than other options and avoids the issues associated with JNI.

Disclaimer: I am the author of the `jhdf` library.

Answer (score 0):

Another API to handle HDF5 files in Java is [HDFql](https://www.hdfql.com). One of its main features is to be declarative. This makes handling HDF5 files (much) easier as you just tell HDFql *what* to do instead of telling *how* to do it when using one of the aforementioned APIs (all of them are imperative).