# What is the easiest way to write uint32 data from a hdf5 file to an array in java?

Tags: java, hdf5

i have an hdf5 file with a table *264x264x1024* filled with `uint32` Numbers. 
I have problems understanding how to get to the data of hdf5-files from within java. 
I want to write the data from the table to an array. 
Is there an easy way to do it?

Sadly the system i am working on is still java6.

Sorry if the question is not very specific, if you need more information to help me please ask. As i said, i dont know alot about hdf5 yet.

Thank you

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227099/hdf5-in-java-what-are-the-difference-between-the-availabe-apis?rq=1). A programmer's first instinct would be looking for existing libraries. Please consider trying one (e.g. JHDF5), then only ask if you stumble upon a more specific issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the easiest ways to solve this would be to abstract oneself from the low-level details of HDF5 files in Java. You can do this
by using HDFql (Hierarchical Data Format query language - http://www.hdfql.com).

Assuming that your HDF5 file is named `my_file.h5` and it stores a dataset named `my_dataset` (dimensions 264x264x1024 of uint32), you
could read this into a Java array using HDFql as follows:

```
// import HDFql package (make sure it can be found by the Java compiler/JVM)
import as.hdfql.*;

public class Example
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int data[][][] = new int[264][264][1024];
        int x;
        int y;
        int z;

        // select (i.e. read) a dataset name "my_dataset" from HDF5 file "my_file.h5" and store it in variable "data"
        HDFql.execute("SELECT FROM my_file.h5 my_dataset INTO MEMORY " + HDFql.variableTransientRegister(data));

        // display content of variable "data"
        for(x = 0; x < 264; x++)
        {
            for(y = 0; y < 264; y++)
            {
                for(z = 0; z < 1024; z++)
                {
                    System.out.println(data[x][y][z]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This example was successfully run using Java 8 and HDFql version 2.1.0. Additionally, please keep in mind that:

1. Java does not support unsigned datatypes such as `uint32` (you will have to somehow make the conversion by yourself);
2. You may run into an `OutOfMemoryError` exception if there is not enough heap space for Java to store an array with these dimensions
   (to solve this, you will have to play with the parameter `-Xmx` when launching Java).

Comment: Thank you! That helped a lot :)